# Integral transform and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I was trying to study deeply the Fourier Transform and I was wondering why the use of this kind of kernel for this integral transform. Could you also suggest me an “engineer with good math knowledge comprehensive” book” about integral transform?

cheers